# Is pin the correct choice in Xamarin.Forms map

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to accomplish something similar with the pins as airbnb does on their map (example https://www.airbnb.com/s/london/homes?allow_override%5B%5D=&s_tag=I6cNOfCg). A pin with some information, when it's pressed it's shows some more information.

I've looked around and it seems like useing pins or custom pins is the only choice? Or is their another way to do this? Is their any plugin to do this? 
In other case, will it be a lot of work/code to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes. pins is the way to go.

Comment: Creating a Custom Pin implementation is most definetly the way to go. Xamarin has a sample on that @ https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/customized-pin/. Since both Android and iOS use different mapping components creating a custom pin and renderers for each platform is your only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pin is definitly the way to go.

Here's a simple usage example:

```
public static Page GetMapPage ()
{   
    var map = new Map (MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius (new Position (37, -122), Distance.FromMiles (10)));

    //If Label is not set, runtime exception
    var pin = new Pin () {
        Position = new Position (37, -122),
        Label = "Some Pin!"
    };
    map.Pins.Add (pin);

    var cp = new ContentPage { 
        Content = map, 
    };

    return cp;
}
```

Note that you can choose between 4 different types of pins when instantiating a new `Pin` using the `PinType` property

[image: PinType]

If you want to create your custom pin implementation, please refer to this well explained [link refering to Xamarin guides](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/customized-pin/).

Hope it helps!